# Using swap with object suicide

Tags: c++, boost

I'm looking at the [Boost.Any source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/any.hpp) and the implementation of `void clear()` looks like this:

```
void clear() BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
   any().swap(*this);
}
```

It basically creates a temporary and swaps the data with the temporary that the temporary will then delete in it's destructor. I would've simply written :

```
void clear() BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
  delete content;
  content = 0;
}
```

Other than the method `swap` being a simple one-liner are there any other (dis)advantages to this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version works because it does the work of the destructor - `delete content` - followed by the work of the default constructor - `content = 0`. I could only be fairly sure that your implementation was correct by checking the code in any.hpp.

The Boost version does the same work without repeating the code of the constructor and destructor. It would carry on working if the implementation changed. I could also be fairly sure that it was correct without looking at the rest of the source.

Comment: Yes I know what's happening, my question is _why?_ Why create an extra object only to swap the contents while you can simply clear and set it yourself.

Comment: You asked what the (dis)advantages to your approach were. I think that answers the "why" question. Are you concerned that the Boost implementation does extra work?

Answer (score 2):

It's about modularity, and about not repeating yourself.

Your version effectively runs the destructor and constructor logic in multiple places. The original code devolves that power, through `swap` (which needs to be defined anyway), to the destructors and constructors themselves so that you do not need to maintain it in two places.

The functional end result is the same.